# Why does my express-session variable not get saved if I set it from in a nested query function?

Tags: node.js, express, session-variables

The following code handles post requests to my application's login page.

If the login credentials are correct it sets the `is_logged_in` session variable to `true` as well as the `user_id` to the user id fetched from a database.

In the query that gets the credentials, if everything passes I have a second query that gets the student id. For some odd reason when I try to set the `req.session.student_id` variable and log the session object I don't see it, it only sets the `is_logged_in` and `user_id` variables that are set from outside the second query function.

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT id, username, password FROM authorizedusers;", 
      (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if(req.body.username === result[i].username 
               && req.body.password === result[i].password){

            con.query(`SELECT id FROM students WHERE user_id = 
              ${result[i].id};`, (err, result) => {

                    if(err) throw err;
                    
                    req.session.student_id = result[0].id;
                });
                
                req.session.is_logged_in = true;
                req.session.user_id = result[i].id;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }

        }
        return res.render('login', {
            msg: "Error! Invalid Credentials!"
        });
    });
});
```

This is what I get when I log the session object.

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  is_logged_in: true,
  user_id: 3
}
```

However, if I try to set the `student_id` in the same scope as the other ones, as follows:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT id, username, password FROM authorizedusers;", 
      (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if(req.body.username === result[i].username 
              && req.body.password === result[i].password){

                con.query(`SELECT id FROM students WHERE user_id = 
                  ${result[i].id};`, (err, result) => {

                    if(err) throw err;
                    
                });
                
                req.session.student_id = "test";
                req.session.is_logged_in = true;
                req.session.user_id = result[i].id;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }

        }
        return res.render('login', {
            msg: "Error! Invalid Credentials!"
        });
    });
});
```

It does work, and this is what I get after when I log the session object.

```
Session {
  cookie: { path: '/', _expires: null, originalMaxAge: null, httpOnly: true },
  student_id: 'test',
  is_logged_in: true,
  user_id: 3
}
```

Why does this happen, and how can I fix it?

**update**

[jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) Answered my question, and said that I could solve my issue by using the mysql2 module instead of the mysql module.

I would like to use the mysql module though. So I would appriceate if somebody could answer how solve this issue while using the mysql module.

Comment: The second `conn.query` hasn't returned yet and node jumped to the next lines. To have correct behaviour, you need to return a valid message only if the `then` returns some data after executing the query.

Comment: @RahulSharma could you pls post a code example.

Answer (score 5):

This is because of the non-blocking, asynchronous nature of the `con.query()` function call.  It starts the asynchronous operation and then executes the lines of code after it.  Then, sometime LATER, it calls its callback.  So, in this code of yours with my adding logging:

```
router.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    con.query("SELECT id, username, password FROM authorizedusers;", (err, result) => {
        if(err) throw err;

        for(var i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
            if(req.body.username === result[i].username && req.body.password === result[i].password){
                con.query(`SELECT id FROM students WHERE user_id = ${result[i].id};`, (err, result) => {
                    if(err) throw err;
                    console.log("got student_id");
                    req.session.student_id = result[0].id;
                });
                req.session.is_logged_in = true;
                req.session.user_id = result[i].id;
                console.log("redirecting and finishing request");
                return res.redirect('/');
            }

        }
        return res.render('login', {
            msg: "Error! Invalid Credentials!"
        });
    });
});
```

You would get this logging:

```
redirecting and finishing request
got student_id
```

So, you finished the request BEFORE you got the `student_id` and set it into the session.   Thus, when you go to immediately try to use the data from the session, it isn't there yet.

---

This is not a particularly easy problem to solve without promises because you have an older-style asynchronous call inside a `for` loop.  This would be much easier if you use the promise interface for your SQL library as then you can sequence things and can use `await` to run only one query at a time - your current loop is running all the queries from the `for` loop in parallel which is not going to make it easy to select the one winner and stop everything else.

If you switch to `mysql2` and then use the promise version:

```
const mysql = require('mysql2/promise');
```

Then, you can do something like this (I'm no expert on mysql2, but hopefully you can see the idea for how you use a promise interface to solve your problem):

```
router.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        const [rows, fields] = await con.query("SELECT id, username, password FROM authorizedusers;");
        for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
            if (req.body.username === rows[i].username && req.body.password === rows[i].password) {
                let [students, fields] = await con.query(`SELECT id FROM students WHERE user_id = ${rows[i].id};`);
                req.session.student_id = students[0].id;
                req.session.is_logged_in = true;
                req.session.user_id = rows[i].id;
                return res.redirect('/');
            }
        }
        return res.render('login', { msg: "Error! Invalid Credentials!" });
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
        res.sendStatus(500);
    }
});
```

Your existing implementation has other deficiencies too that are corrected with this code:

1. The loop variable declared with `var` will never be correct inside the asynchronous callback function.
2. Your `if (err) throw err` error handling is insufficient.  You need to capture the error, log it and send an error response when you get an error in a response handler.
3. You will always call `res.render()` before any of the database calls in the loop complete.

Comment: This is only the test phase of the application, I am just trying to get it running. I'll handle the errors properly later.. Thanks though!                                                                                                 Could you explain issues 1 and 3 in more detail pls.                                                                                                                                                        I would like to know a little more about mysql2 before using it, Is there any way I could use promises with my current code?

Comment: @BeeFriedman - Issues 1 and 3 are already explained in the text of the answer.  It would have been nice if you asked a more specific question about what I've already written.  `con.query()` is non-blocking and asynchronous.  It calls it's callback LATER.  Meanwhile, the `for` loop keeps running and the `for` loop is actually done before ANY of the callbacks are called.  Thus, your `var` declared loop variable is sitting on it's terminal value for ALL the callbacks.  `let` makes a new and separate loop variable for each iteration and thus each callback gets its own variable with the value.

Comment: @BeeFriedman - Proper error handling should NEVER be written later.  It actually needs to be factored into the ORIGINAL design.  I've been teaching young programmers this concept for years.  It is a disaster to "get your code running" without any proper error handling.  It's a core fundamental part of the design and has to be considered from the beginning.  In fact, you would have discovered that with your original implementation, it's very, very, very difficult to add proper error handling to that design after the fact.  In fact, you need a different design that accounts for error handling.

Comment: @BeeFriedman - mysql2 is just a future version of mysql that adds a promise interface.  You could manually add a promise interface to mysql, but why do that when the work has already been done for you in mysql2.  IMO, nobody should be programming asynchronous operation in Javascript without promises any more.  Promises are the core component in the language for handling asynchronous operations and programming without them is way, way harder, particularly when you have multiple asynchronous operations and need decent error handling.  Even more so when you have branching (which you have).

Comment: Thanks! I will look in to mysql2. Sorry for the headache I am still new to web development.

Answer (score 0):

It can be sometimes that the express session is saved when the out direct handler/function finished.

On that situation, if you want to  save your session within a new async function, you should add the `next` function variable in your handler.

Then use it as the callback function to save you session.

It should look like this:

```js
router.post('/login', (req, res, next) => {
    con.query(..., 
      (err, result) => {
        for(...) {
            if(...){

                res.redirect('/'); 
                next();
                return;
            }

        }
        res.render('login', {
            msg: "Error! Invalid Credentials!"
        });
        next();
        return;
    });
});
```

Before it happens, make use your code is executed correctly.